# Voltage drop in system supply with Li-on battery

Tags: batteries, pcb, charging

I have a problem with the system illustrated below.

[image]

Li-on battery shows 8,2V when fully charged. When I connect it to the system, the voltage of the battery drops to 7,4V.
When I unplug the tablet's charging cable, I can read 8,2V again.

What is the reason for the voltage drop here? Can anyone help with this?

Comment: pull 1.5A from the battery via resistor and look at the voltage across the resistor (before it burns). It could be the internal resistance of the battery

Comment: What are the characteristics of the battery?

Comment: Values written on the battery:
Orion
ORN-18650 7.4V 12000mAh
Rechargeable Li-ion Battery Pack
PCMCODE: BMS-A204(3A)

Comment: So you are using a battery specified as 7.4V and you are surprised when it provides 7.4V? Batteries have some internal resistance, so that the unloaded voltage will be higher than the voltage under load.